# How to display popover on top of Textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I never work on these type of stuff.

I have a textField in my html page.it's code is in below.

```
<div class="span4 mr1 shelflifeDiv">
        <input type="text" id="shelfLifeField" name="Shelf Life" placeholder="Shelf Life" class="po1 pull-right" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html=true data-trigger="click" data-content> 
    </div>
```

My requirement is,If you click on that field,I want to display popover,for this my web designer given the following template.

```
 <script id="shelflifePopover" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
    <div class='row-fluid'>
            <div class='span8'><span>Maximum Time</span></div>
            <div class='span8'><input type='text' id='po1_maxtime' placeholder='Shelf life' class='mr2' disabled></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

he said,whenever you want to render popover on top of textField,just add the template code to the `data-content` attribute of textField.

As per his suggestion, using `setAttribute` I appended that template code when the field is in focusing state.

If cursor out of text-field,I want to remove(hide)popover on top of textField.

I tried to add template code to data-content attribute,but it's not working.

```
var ele=document.getElementById("shelfLifeField");
//I compiled template code and assigned to compileCode variable. 
ele.setAttribute("data-content",compileCode);
```

please can anyone help me,Totally I stuck here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following jquery code to show bootstrap popover, pls see the working [fiddle](http://bootply.com/92160) here

```
$(function () {
                var showPopover = function () {
                    $(this).popover('show');
                }
                , hidePopover = function () {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
                };

                $('#fb').popover({
                    content: 'Facebook',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement:'top'
                })
            $('#tw').popover({
                    content: 'Twitter',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement:'top'
                }) 
            $('#tb').popover({
                    content: 'tumblr',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement:'top'
                })  
            $('#fl').popover({
                    content: 'flickr',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement:'top'
                })  
            $('#yt').popover({
                    content: 'youtube',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement:'top'
                })            
                .focus(showPopover)
                .blur(hidePopover)
                .hover(showPopover, hidePopover);
            });
```